# How to emit FormData object in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to emit a FormData object in from child component to parent Component. Here is some code what I'm trying:

**Child Component**

```
onAddFile(error, file) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(this.fileName, file.file);
  console.log(...formData); // here it show the output
  this.$emit("input", formData);  // not working here
}
```

I am trying to store the emitted data in a object in parent component. but it just stores a String. In the case of `console.log` it shows following.
[image]

How to solve it ?

Comment: How are you handling the `$emit("input")` function in parent page??

Comment: by v-model binding

Comment: can you show some code from parent component of how you are handling the data?

Answer (score 1):

In your parent, you could watch for the emit event with (to at least debug)

```html
<div @input="captureFormData"></div>
```

```js
methods: {
  captureFormData(capturedData) {
    console.log('captured here', capturedData)
  }
}
```

You could also use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) but it is *gently* deprecated in Vue3 AFAIK.

Here is a reminder on how [`v-model` works on components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

```html
<input v-model="searchText">
<!-- is equivalent to -->
<input
  :value="searchText"
  @input="searchText = $event.target.value"
>
```

So, if your logic works with this snippet, it may work here too.